# Recompiling open-jdk, there is no makefile

Tags: java, make, openjdk

I have modified a source file in open-jdk-6 and now want to rebuild it. In all guides it is stated that the build process is done via `make`. However I don't see any Makefile or target.

```
 $ pwd
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

 $ ls
 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION  com   docs     java   jre       lib  org     src.zip  sunw
 bin                 demo  include  javax  launcher  man  sample  sun      THIRD_PARTY_README
```

I am using Ubuntu-AMD64

**UPDATE**

I have installed the sources according to dpkg command

```
$ dpkg -l | grep jdk
ii  openjdk-6-dbg                                  6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1          Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
ii  openjdk-6-demo                                   6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1          Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
ii  openjdk-6-jdk                                  6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1          OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-6-jre                                  6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-6-jre-headless                          6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-6-jre-lib                              6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1          OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
ii  openjdk-6-source                               6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1          OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
```

Comment: What did you modify? You only have a binary distribution, not the source tree.

Comment: I modified a sun/misc/somethings.java. please see the updated post

Comment: The source code isn't something you install with `apt-get`. It's available on the project's homepage, [here](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/).